# How can I split a string by a delimiter in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Here's the code snippet from my Makefile:

```
%/foo: %/bar.yaml
    $(BINARY) generate -g go \
        --package-name {COOL_VALUE}
# COOL_VALUE should be the parent folder of a `foo`, e.g., `foo1/foo2/foo -> foo2`
```

the question is how can I split `$@` string by `/` to get the second last element:

E.g.,

```
make foo1/foo2/foo
> ./binary generate -g go \
   --package-name foo2

make foo3/foo
> ./binary generate -g go \
   --package-name foo3
```

My attempts:
I came up with

```
$(eval package_name := $(word 1,$(subst /, ,$@)))
% pick second last element somehow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really talking about `/` as a delimiter, then your best bet is to use the filename functions like this:

```
PARENT = $(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $@)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(eval package_folders := $(filter-out foo,$(subst /, ,$@)))
    $(eval package_name := $(word $(words $(package_folders)), $(package_folders)))
    @echo "$(package_name)"
```